Training job in sagemaker from local notebook
I have a Python file in which I preprocessing the data using Python codes by calling data from Amazon s3, and then using the LightGBM algorithm to train the data, and finally using the SageMaker parser, I want save the final model in the SageMaker environment.
'SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN, SM_CHANNEL_TEST'
I want to execute this task by calling this file and the method of Fit sckitlearn in my local Joyter notebook and see the execution in Amazon Sage Maker. When I run the fit method, the job starts, but I don't see anything running training job or log in Sage Maker.
Please help if anyone can.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
